# Error when uploading file to S3: PutObject error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Below is the error every-time I try to upload an image to my bucket

```
Error executing \"PutObject\" on "https://xxxxxxbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/img1.png"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6:

(see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Now first, cURL error 6 according to curl error html link in error says "Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved."

Every issue on forums regarding cURL error 6 was mostly happening due to wrong name of 'region' being provided. In my case it is correct 'us-west-1' for North California. I have been using other buckets in same region for other apps. This is another reason why I am very puzzled.

Second, my IAM user has access to that bucket. I even used admin access keys to see if something was wrong with my policy for my iAM user. Same error. I also wondered if anything wrong with permission then I should have gotten "forbidden error" instead of "unresolved error". I set my bucket to public explicitly just to debug and same error.

Third, I tried mutiple ways to upload to s3:

```
//First way
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($filename, file_get_contents($value -> getRealPath()));

//Second way
$client = new S3Client([
'credentials' => [
    'key'    => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxx'
],
    'region' => 'us-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
]);

$adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($client, 'xxxxxbucket');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
$filesystem -> put($filename, file_get_contents($value -> getRealPath()));
```

Lastly, I have checked received files on my Laravel end and they are fine.

I am testing on local machine. I deployed the code to my beanstalk environment to see If it was issue on my local development side but staging server giving same error.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you double checked the bucket name is correct?

Comment: yes name is correct. To confirm that I used the link on error https://xxxxxxbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
It opens and browser give download alert prompt, if it was set to public which I mentioned that I did explicitly set it to public just to test.

Comment: Is the application being run as a container on your local as well as Elastic Beanstalk? Are you able to resolve other public hostnames from you server (for example google).

Comment: @ChrisWilliams in local I am using plain mac terminal to execute artisan serve.
I didn't check ssh connection to ping google. But I wrote guzzlehttp call to google in local. I am unable to resolve google. I do get same cURL error 6 unresolve issue. SO what does this mean?

Comment: I am also wondering since aws lib uses guzzlehttp under the hood. Could guzzlehttp be the main cause?

Comment: Guzzlehttp is an abstraction layer above cURL. If you wanted to remove Guzzle you could just perform either a plain curl request or file_get_contents. But both would likely have same error. It’s seems that there is an issue with the DNS resolution, are you overriding any settings for networking or DNS within either environment?

Comment: yeah it was problem with cURL. I updated my answer on my fix. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, have a great day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause in local development case. It is silly. It seems cURL of my mac and php cURL were different version. mac cURL is 7.54.0 and php using cURL is 7.65.3

So i uninstalled last cURL version

```
brew uninstall curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies
```

and restarted the php

```
brew services restart php
```

Now Its all working.

In case where I mentioned beanstalk was not working too, it was silly ignorant mistake about something else error in code. This one really was my blunder because if I paid more close attention in this case then I could have saved my time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of couple of possible issues

- **From local**: If you are behind `corporate proxy` and not able to `ping` the respective aws host.
- **From deployed beanstalk**: If you are inside `VPC` and not able to access host outside of it directly.